# Specify remote repository in 'hg summary --remote' command

Tags: mercurial

When I run `hg summary --remote`, the output is

```
parent: 1:0447a332a9d5 tip
 "first commit"
branch: default
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
abort: repository default not found!
```

Is there a way to specify remote repository from command line ? (As opposed to adding [default] in hgrc). I understand `summary` is a combination of `incoming` & `outgoing` commands where I can specify the remote repository on command line. However the `summary` command doesn't accept the repo name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use additional option

```
--config CONFIG [+] set/override config option (use 'section.name=value')
```

for adding run-time parameter of default path. Because in .hgrc it's

```
[paths]
default = URL
```

your addition can be smth. like `--config 'paths.default=URL'`

Comment: I do not want to add it in hgrc, just one time use from command line

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I didn't read your answer carefully. It worked (without the single quotes after --config).